# CVE-2016-5195 - impacts on virtualization

Tags: virtualization, cve, kvm

I wonder if the recently found [CVE-2016-5195](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1384344) can be used to break out of KVM or OpenVZ virtualization to gain access to the host system?

Basically, I believe that the local privileges can not be used for that because an attacker would need to have access to the host system.

It's clear for me that the attack could be used inside of a container if the kernel isn't patched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this github page](https://github.com/dirtycow/dirtycow.github.io/wiki/VulnerabilityDetails) and [this RedHat page](https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/2706661) it seems that the attacker can write to /proc/self/mem and ptrace files.
The ACL that will be affected is the ACL of the VM and not the host machine. This means that the files that are shared between the host machine and the VM (remember the VMWare file sharing bugs) will remain vulnerable. Apart from that, I don't think the host machines will get affected.